# setting the shut down hook as non daemon

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown

when my java app closes - my shut down hook doesnt run fully till the end.
in the java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) it mentions that

> Shutdown hooks should also finish their work quickly...

(refer to the doc) as it closes the app quick.
I want to try and solve it (maybe set it to non daemon thread)

So I tried first to reconstruct it using a simple app.
I add the hook using

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
        @Override public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }

        }
    });
```

and I throw a

```
            System.exit(1);
```

in this example the shutdown process counts until the end with no problem.
(So no reconstraction)

How can I fix it in my app?
How can I reconstruct it ?

Comment: "reconstruct" what specifically?

Comment: what does your shutdown hook do and when does it stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc is giving a recommendation.  If the JVM is going down, your hooks should not be running for minutes doing various things.  They are designed to cleanup after the program.

The hook threads are started and then `join()` is called on them so the JVM *always* waits for them to complete before stopping.  Here's the code from `ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks()`:

```
static void runHooks() {
    ...
    for (Thread hook : threads) {
        hook.start();
    }
    for (Thread hook : threads) {
        hook.join();
    }
}
```

This said, if you call `System.exit(1);`, the JVM will exit immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your application in a container? It may be possible that the container is killing the JVM after some timeout once you have initiated the stop/shutdown. 
In normal situations the shutdown hooks should all finish, and this way they will delay the JVM shutdown time, but *In rare circumstances the virtual machine may abort, that is, stop running without shutting down cleanly. This occurs when the virtual machine is terminated externally, for example with the SIGKILL signal on Unix or the TerminateProcess call on Microsoft Windows. The virtual machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example, corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access nonexistent memory. If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.*